# App Performance on Raspberry Pi vs multi Xeon core server

Tags: php, performance, raspberry-pi, cpu-usage, server

I am developing an App on a Raspberry Pi using PHP and mySQL. After couple of weeks of development I have noticed that in some cases the App runs slow and then I try to optimise the code related (e.g. too many loops within loops, or loading of static images dynamically is really slow on RPi). Usually the slow-downs would not be felt at all on a more powerful hardware, but I decided that those slowdowns would be noticeable when the server hardware resources are maxed-out.

The question:
Would the application performance optimisations on a Raspberry Pi allow me to achieve better results on a multi-code multi-socket Xeon server later? e.g. would I be able to reach more hits per second before maxing out the hardware resources when I take this approach by developing my App on a less powerful hardware? Or is it just a waste of time and the performance gains are not worth it?

I am asking this because the architecture of RPi and Xeon is very different and whatever I am doing might be a waste of time. As I do not have a Xeon server at the moment, I am not able to compare and prove my point above at all. :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon what type of optimizations you are doing. Portability across different hardware all comes down to the architectural independences of the abstractions you are using (e.g. language, compiler, libraries). My understanding of PHP is that it works at a very high level as an interpreter intended to be as portable as possible. So it is already abstracted from the hardware.

My guess is that your optimizations will carry across to the Xeon. I figure you're doing algorithmic and code optimizations, such as researching better methods of doing something, replacing loops with more efficient code, using better data structures, and getting rid of unnecessary and redundant calls. All that will help on any machine.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was doing - "such as researching better methods of doing something, replacing loops with more efficient code, using better data structures, and getting rid of unnecessary and redundant calls". Nice to hear somebody agreeing with me. Thanks! :)